# AngularJS input field shows [object Object] after submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have developed a AngularJS weather application and the only problem i have left to solve has to do with my input element. After a value has been submitted, the input value is replaced with "[object Object]". I have read through several questions and haven't come across anything that has helped me solve this problem thus far. So I turn to you guys and hope you can assist me.

the form and input is as follows:

```
<form name="add-city" ng-submit="getCity(city)">
    <input id="user-city" type="text" name="user-city" placeholder="Search for a city" ng-model="city" ></input>
    <button type="button" ng-click="getCity(city)">Add</button>
</form>
```

The controller with getCity(city) function is as follows:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','forecasts','$http', function($scope, forecasts, $http){
    forecasts.success(function(data){
        $scope.forecasts = data.list;
    });
    $scope.removeCity = function (index) {
        $scope.forecasts.splice(index, 1);
        urlCityList.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem('myCities', JSON.stringify(urlCityList));
    };
    $scope.getCity = function(city) {
        console.log('getCity() invoked with: '+city);
        var thisCity=$scope.city;
        // CONSTRUCT URL
        var url1 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=';
        var url2 = '&units=metric&APPID=f96088515ba4137e85db097513d9d8ab';
        var getCityUrl = url1+$scope.city+url2;
        $http.get(getCityUrl)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.city = data;
            var newCity = {
                "city": $scope.city.name,
                "country":$scope.city.sys.country,
                "id":$scope.city.id
            }
            var getCorrectCity = newCity.city.toUpperCase() == city.toUpperCase();
            var avoidDuplicate = true;
            var noDuplicate = true;
            for (i=0; i < urlCityList.length; i++) {
                if (urlCityList[i].city.toUpperCase() == city.toUpperCase()) {
                    noDuplicate = false;
                }
            }
            if (getCorrectCity == true && noDuplicate == true) {
                urlCityList.push(newCity);
                localStorage.setItem('myCities', JSON.stringify(urlCityList))
                $scope.forecasts.push($scope.city);
            }
        })
        .error(function(err){   
            return err;
        });
        console.log($('#addCity').val());
        $('#addCity').val('');
    };
    $("#user-city").keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        // Do something
    }
});
}]);
```

the app is live and the issue can be seen here: jhalland.dk/weather

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are saving `data` object to `$scope.city` in the `success` response.

If you want the name of the city inside `$scope.city` save as `$scope.city = data.name`

Answer (score 1):

Amended what I think is happening.

```
.success(function(data){
      // $scope.city = data; - causes [object Object]
      var newCity = {
           "city": data.name,
           "country":data.sys.country,
           "id":data.id
      }
...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In *line 19* of your `MainController`, you have set `$scope.city` to be an `object`, rather than a `string`. Since your HTML can't show the object's value in an `input`, it shows that it IS an `object` instead.

If you change -:

From

```
$scope.city = data;
var newCity = {
    "city": $scope.city.name,
    "country":$scope.city.sys.country,
    "id":$scope.city.id
}
```

To

```
var newCity = {
    "city": data.name,
    "country": data.sys.country,
    "id": data.id
}
```

OR

```
$scope.city = data.name;
```

It should work fine.